# The toolbar of TextFormField is under the AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar, flutter-textformfield

I have a `StatefulWidget` named `Root` and this is the start address of my application. The `Root` widget contains the single and common `AppBar` of the application, but its body varies.

My question is: I have a page named `SearchPlaces` and that page uses the common `AppBar` of the application. There is a `TextFormField` under the `AppBar`. When I press and hold the `TextFormField`, the toolbar menu (copy, cut, select all, paste, etc.) is under the `AppBar`. How do I prevent this? I want the toolbar to appear

[image]

`root.dart`

```dart
class Root extends StatefulWidget {
  const Root({super.key});

  @override
  State<Root> createState() => _RootState();
}

class _RootState extends State<Root> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Root build");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        forceMaterialTransparency: true,
        scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 90,
            height: 80,
            child: _ChangeThemeToggleButton(animationController: _animationController),
          ).onlyPadding(right: PaddingManager.commonHorizontal),
        ],
      ),
      body: Observer(
        name: "Center",
        builder: (_) {
          return Center(
            child: NavigatorRoutes()
                .navPages
                .elementAt(GetRooteStateManager.rootStateManager.selectedIndexOfBottomNavigationBar),
          ).symmetricpadding(
            horizontal: PaddingManager.commonHorizontal,
            vertical: PaddingManager.commonVertical,
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const CustomBottomNavigationBar(
              // themeState: GetThemeStateManager().themeStateManager,
              )
          .onlyPadding(
        left: PaddingManager.horizontalOfBottomNavigationBar,
        right: PaddingManager.horizontalOfBottomNavigationBar,
        bottom: PaddingManager.onlyBottomOfBottomNavigationBar,
        top: PaddingManager.onlyTopOfBottomNavigationBar,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`search_places.dart`

```dart
class SearchPlaces extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchPlaces({super.key});

  @override
  State<SearchPlaces> createState() => _SearchPlacesState();
}

class _SearchPlacesState extends State<SearchPlaces> with TextFormFieldValidationMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    searchController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final places = List.generate(20, (index) => "Place $index");

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Overlay(
        initialEntries: [
          OverlayEntry(
            builder: (context) => Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SearchTextFormField(controller: searchController),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: places.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(places[index]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

search_text_form_field.dart

```
class SearchTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchTextFormField({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    double height = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;

    return SizedBox(
      width: width * 0.9,
      height: height * 0.06,
      child: Observer(
        builder: (context) => TextFormField(
          contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
            return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
              anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
              buttonItems: <ContextMenuButtonItem>[
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.copy,
                ),
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.selectAll(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.selectAll,
                ),
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.cut,
                ),
                ContextMenuButtonItem(
                  onPressed: () {
                    editableTextState.pasteText(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar);
                  },
                  type: ContextMenuButtonType.paste,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          enableInteractiveSelection: true,
          onChanged: (value) {
            value.isNotEmpty
                ? GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.changeClearButtonState(isActive: true)
                : GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.changeClearButtonState(isActive: false);
          },
          controller: controller,
          autofocus: true,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
          maxLines: 1,
          autocorrect: false,
          onTapOutside: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.isActiveClearButton
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      controller.clear();
                      GetSearchPlacesStateManager.searchPlacesManager.changeClearButtonState(isActive: false);
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.clear_outlined),
                  )
                : null,
            hintText: "Search Places",
            prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindy, provide code for `TextFormField `.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the scaffold with SafeArea widget

```
SafeArea(
child: Scaffold(......)
,);
```

then wrap the SearchPlaces Scaffold's body (overlay)

```
    Container(
 margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05),
    child : overlay(....)
    ,),
```

keep adjusting the MediaQuery height (exemple: * 0.05 )until you reach the perfect size

Comment: it didn't work. I wrapped scaffold of SearchPlaces with SafeArea but result is same. Toolbar is showing at under of AppBar

Comment: okay wrap the  SearchPlaces  Scaffold's body (overlay) with container then  inside that conatiner add margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),

Comment: This works for me but will be space between TextFormField and AppBar and I don't want that. Have you different idea ?

Comment: your edited answer didn't work. Actually I solved using onlypadding on TextFormField but will be space between TextFormField and AppBar. How can we provide showing on AppBar the toolbar. Real question should be that

Comment: try this AppBar(
      forceMaterialTransparency: true,
...
)

Comment: I'm so sorry :( This case is amazing....

Comment: don't give up bro try Hideable package and hide the appbar when touching the TextField

Comment: Thanks for all bro I'll try that package. :)